# Apply CSS to iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I add iframe from external site to mine like this:

```
<iframe src="http://site.com/page/"></iframe>
```

It has some own css and javascript files.

**How can I add my own css styles to this iframe?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the iframe source is not the same domain as your site, you can't add your own CSS to it due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: @Happy: SOP applies to Javascript as well.

Comment: Only trick I can think of is to use a serverside proxy, but thats a can of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to format the iframe border or its content? The latter isn't allowed for security reasons, the former can be archieved with a simple stylesheet (selector "iframe").

Comment: it adds overlay and some text, I want to change the colors and some styles.

Comment: If the overlay is a frame, I think that it's not possible.