# How to render a div 100% wide in Internet Explorer Quirksmode

Tags: css, iframe, html, quirks-mode

I have a `div` in an `iframe`. The div is supposed to render at 100% width. Looking at the document **not** in an iframe, the div does indeed render at 100%. When in an iframe however, it renders at 90 - 95%. According to the MS developer tool the iframe, and indeed the body of the iframe document are both at 100%. It's just the div that is not. The HTML:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" 
 src="http://localhost:8080/pagedetails/73/true" id="su3-frame" 
 hspace="0" vspace="0" 
 leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0">

     <html style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt;" 
           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

       <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" id="su3-body" 
             leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" 
             style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt;">

         <div id="su3-header" 
              leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" 
              marginwidth="0" topmargin="0">

       </body>
     </html>
</iframe>
```

and the css for the frame and div:

```
iframe#su3-frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border: 0;    
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 100000000;
}

div#su3-header { 
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px; 
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 56px; 
  position: absolute; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  top: 0; left: 0; 
  background: url('/images/bg-90.png');
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #aaa; 
}
```

Any thoughts, suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `iframe`, you're free to specify whatever doctype you want; you can escape from Quirks Mode, and it won't affect the "parent page".

In my test (which I'm not *entirely* sure matches your test case), changing the first two lines of my document included via `iframe` to (for example) these :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

(*that's the HTML5 doctype*) puts the `iframe` document into Standards Mode, and fixes the issue.

Comment: ah yes, there is no doctype in the frame doc. There should be. I'll take a look.

Comment: @thirtydoc - actually the doctype is specified, had a copy-paste failure. It's <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: Can you edit your original question with the entire code from both files so I can test it?

Comment: @30dot: I am being an idiot - I was switching the doc mode in MS dev tool bar to quirksmode - but of course i don't need to do this as I have the doctype set for the iframe! Facepalming myself. So for ie7 & 8 am fine. (ie6 I can't face right now...) Marking you correct. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You're not trying to apply the parent's CSS to the iFrame, are you?  You might be bumping up against the Same Origin Policy

[Apply CSS to iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064560/apply-css-to-iframe)

Do you NEED an iFrame?  As a professional UI Developer I think I've had to use one 3 or 4 times in total over a 15 year career.  Most of what people use iFrames for can be overcome with the Dom and Ajax these days.  And, if you're trying to call an iframe out of the same domain, in theory you could just grab that content via includes.

Comment: Well the iframe and the parent page do use the same css file, but they are included seperately in each doc. Could this be a problem? As for using an iframe, decided to do this as 1) it stops your css being clobbered by the page and 2) some sites have js which does stuff to all elements on the page, again clobbering your css and even html. See my other question here for more background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016105/iframe-in-internet-explorer-quirks-mode-will-not-render-at-100-width

Comment: One of the beauties of CSS is that it's CASCADING.  So, best practice is to start macro--like in your linked example--and declare the base styles.  Then, you override as needed via CSS for the lesser elements in the document.  You shouldn't need to iFrame something to get around styles, just override them to what you want in your CSS document.  Work logically, putting the macro styles on the top of the document and working down to micro.  Just like separate stylesheets for separate browsers, this is an unnecessary hack.